# How do I stop a specific WiFi network from turning on WiFi automatically in Oreo

Tags: wi-fi, 8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy-s7

### Background:

With my Samsung Galaxy S7 finally updated to Android Oreo recently, I got the option to turn on WiFi automatically when in places where I frequently am.
This is a great feature, which I used to achieve using Llama, and which I very much want to use.

However, there doesn't seem to be any control for the locations or networks that trigger it. I also have no idea how big the range is of what it counts as a distinct location.

The issue is that there is this WiFi network throughout the city which I use at one specific location frequently. I pass through the vicinity of that location several times a day, which unfortunately means WiFi is turned on every time. Which in turn means my phone is continuously trying to connect to that network and failing, because I'm just biking through. All the while it prevents a stable connection with my mobile network, because it's trying to connect to the WiFi.

### Question:

Is there any way to prevent a specific location from triggering WiFi to turn on automatically?

Or, for that matter, is anything known about how the option precisely works? I'm assuming it looks at location, but how big is the range, how does it work if I connect to the same network in different locations, etc.?

Comment: No idea about Samsung ROMs but in WiFi preferences I have "Turn on WiFi automatically". Is this what you mean by "option to turn on WiFi automatically when in places where I frequently am"?

Comment: @SSS: Yes, that is the option I mean.

Comment: You can try an automation appoach usiing Tasker /Macrodroid or others. Define a Geofence and disable wifi on entering that and enable on exit

Comment: So I'm not sure how that option works but it's probably one of these two ways. Tracking location, if it track location and turn on WiFi it shouldn't have issues as far as location services are ON range shouldn't be much big if I had to guess I would have to say 20-30m. If it looks into available WiFi networks and if X is available then it connects, this is possible due to every newer phone scans almost always for WiFi and Bluetooth signals, in this case of there is some WiFi with same name (SSID) anywhere else it will turn on WiFi there.

Comment: What range we are talking about does it turn on WiFi half of kilometre away or?

Comment: @Једноруки Крстивоје: I have no idea what the range is, because I don't actually know what it decided as the location. My city is quite dense, so there is a lot of stuff quite close to each other.

Comment: To be honest it seems I didn't read entire question. So this actually works on recognising SSID or name of WiFi so if it's in range you will be connected. To make it specific location you'll need to use something else

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје I honestly don't know whether it looks at location, the SSID, or both. So if my question implies one or the other, that is unintended. Regardless of the actual trigger, I would like to know how to remove a specific trigger from the internal list of triggers.

Comment: Well you'll probably need to use app like tasker, and you should maybe change your question "how do I automate X in X app" look into beeshyams comment up there

Comment: While that would be a potential workaround, that simply isn't what I was asking, so I see no point in changing the question to something completely different. I want to know how Android deals with this.

Answer (score 0):

So, if the WiFi turned on automatically and is connecting to the network, you need to turn the WiFi off.
When I did that, I got the following notification:

> **Turn on Wi-Fi automatically**
>   "[*SSID*]" has been removed from your frequently used Wi-Fi networks.
>   It will be added again if you use it more often.

Apparently that is enough to remove it temporarily at least. No idea how long it takes until it is added again.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't take too long. Probably about 2 weeks, but it probably depends on the frequency as well.